# Middle click detected by xev, but nothing responds to it

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, mouse, manjaro, antergos

I'm running Antergos (Arch 4.6.2.1-ARCH), and am using a Corsair K70 mouse.

I first noticed this problem when I went from Manjaro KDE edition over to Manjaro's Gnome edition, at which point Firefox and Gnome in general stopped doing anything when I used the middle click (e.g. Firefox/Chrome opening new links, minimising windows etc.) I tried Antergos Gnome edition as a potential way to rectify this with no joy.

1. List item

   I ran xev expecting the mouse drivers to be the problem, but the output suggests to me there are no problems picking up the button events from the mouse. I've tried mapping the middle click functionality to other mouse buttons to check, and still nothing responds in the expected way.

I can only think that this problem is Gnome, or something I've changed in Gnome.

Comment: I'm running (fully updated) stock Arch with Mate 1.12 and am having similar problems.  In the last week I've noticed that the middle mouse button is no longer working properly; i.e. can't be used to paste the copy buffer and won't open new tabs in firefox.  However, I'm using the GTK2 build of Mate, so if the problem is the same as yours, it's unlikely to be related to gnome.